# Clozel's unpublished manuscript

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, automorphic-forms

I'm looking for Clozel's unpublished manuscript

> L. Clozel, Modular properties of automorphic representations I: Applications of
>   the Selberg trace formula (1993)

cited in Urban's *Eigenvarieties for reductive groups*. A quick internet search proved unsuccessful. Could anyone point me to this?

Comment: Have you tried to contact Clozel directly?

Comment: I haven't. I was hoping to find it easily accessible somewhere, before having to contact him directly. You could say I am shy.. Also it might be nice to know for anyone else who might be wondering.

Comment: I checked [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/au:+Clozel/0/1/0/all/0/1) and it is not there.